# how to connect Restful API and socket server in java

Tags: java, api, sockets, server, httpurlconnection

I created restful API(with maven) which connect to MySQL. I want to connect with the Java socket server I created earlier. But I couldn't figure out how to do this. I tried to connect with HttpURLConnection over Server.java but it didn't connect yet. Is it a good way to connect? Or should i try different way for this? And also I created new maven project and putted Server.Java and Client.Java in it. But it is a just attempt. I am not sure is it necessary or not.

Server.JAVA

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Server {
    //initialize socket and input stream
    private Socket socket   = null;
    private ServerSocket server   = null;
    private DataInputStream in       =  null;

    // constructor with port
    public Server(int port)
    {
        // starts server and waits for a connection
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server started");

            System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");

            socket = server.accept();
            // System.out.println("Client accepted");

            // HttpURLConnection attempt
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/update/3");
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
            String data = "{\n  \"firstName\":\"Can\",\n   \"lastName\":\"Doe\",\n \"occupation\":\"xxx\"\n}";
            byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            stream.write(out);
            System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + http.getResponseMessage());
            http.disconnect();


            System.out.println("Client accepted");


            // takes input from the client socket
            in = new DataInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";

            // reads message from client until "Stop" is sent
            while (!line.equals("Stop"))
            {
                try
                {
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(line);

                }
                catch(IOException i)
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Closing connection");

            // close connection
            socket.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Server server = new Server( 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting in above code? this looks fine to me.

Comment: i didn't get any error. I am just checking on MySQL.  I try to update one of data, but it didn't updated yet. I thought it is about dependency (in pom.xml) or something.

Comment: ` System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + http.getResponseMessage());`, can you check what is output here? this can be one of the hint whats happening in background

Comment: My output is:                                                                                                           
Server started
Waiting for a client ...
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: it means, your rest service is not accepting any connecting from your Server.java. Can you hit REST url via curl or postman & check if its working

Comment: I run my Api code. I got this "200null" from System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + http.getResponseMessage());`

Comment: ok, meaning code is returning http 200, i.e. REST is accepting request & returning response, so mostly you should not have any issue now

Comment: Woww the data updated :) Thank u so much for helping.